# How to convert nested json to data frame with kdb+

Tags: kdb

I am trying to get the data from cryptostats like below, it gives me back a nested json. I want it to be in a table format. How do I do that?

```
query:"https://api.cryptostats.community/api/v1/fees/oneDayTotalFees/2023-02-07";
raw:.Q.hg query;
res:.j.k raw;
```

To get json file, use https://api.cryptostats.community/api/v1/fees/oneDayTotalFees/2023-02-07
To view json code into a table format, use  https://jsongrid.com/json-grid
Final result would be a kdb+ table which has all the cols from nested json output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are all dictionaries

```
q)distinct type each res[`data]
,99h
```

But they do not collapse to a table because they do not all have matching keys

```
q)distinct key each res[`data]
`id`bundle`results`metadata`errors
`id`bundle`results`metadata
```

Looking at a row where errors is populated we can see it is a dictionary

```
q)res[`data;0;`errors]
oneDayTotalFees| "Error executing oneDayTotalFees on compound: Date incomplete"
```

You can create a prototype dictionary with a blank `errors` key in it and join `,` each piece of data onto it. This will result in uniform dictionaries which will be promoted to a table type `98h`

```
q)table:(enlist[`errors]!enlist (`$())!()),/:res`data
q)type table
98h
```

Row which already had `errors` is unaffected:

```
q)table 0
errors  | (,`oneDayTotalFees)!,"Error executing oneDayTotalFees..
id      | "compound"
bundle  | 0n
results | (,`oneDayTotalFees)!,0n
metadata| `source`icon`name`category`description`feeDescription;..
```

Row which previously did not have `errors` now has a valid empty dictionary

```
q)table 1
errors  | (`symbol$())!()
id      | "swapr-ethereum"
bundle  | "swapr"
results | (,`oneDayTotalFees)!,24.78725
metadata| `category`name`icon`bundle`blockchain`description`feeDescription..
```

- https://kx.com/blog/kdb-q-insights-parsing-json-files/
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/join/
- https://code.kx.com/q/kb/faq/#construction
- https://code.kx.com/q/basics/datatypes/
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right

If you want to explore nested objects you can index at depth (see blog post linked above). If you have many sparse keys leaving it like this is efficient for storage:

```
q)select tokenSymbol:metadata[::;`tokenSymbol] from table where not ""~/:metadata[::;`tokenSymbol]
tokenSymbol
-----------
"HNY"
```

If you do wish to explode a nested field you can run similar to:

```
q)table:table,'{flip c!flip table[`metadata]@\:(c:distinct raze key each table[`metadata])}[]
q)meta table
c               | t f a
----------------| -----
errors          |
id              | C
bundle          | C
results         |
metadata        |
source          | C
icon            | C
name            | C
category        | C
description     | C
feeDescription  | C
blockchain      | C
website         | C
tokenTicker     | C
tokenCoingecko  | C
protocolLaunch  | C
tokenLaunch     | C
adapter         | C
subtitle        | C
events          | C
shortName       | C
protocolShutdown| C
tokenSymbol     | C
subcategory     | C
tokenticker     | C
tokencoingecko  | C
```

Care needs to be taken will filling in nulls and keeping consistent types of data in each column. In this dataset the `events` tag inside `metadata` is tabular data:

```
q)select distinct type each events from table
events
------
10
98
0
```

This would need to be cleaned similar to:

```
q)table:update events:count[i]#enlist ([] date:();description:()) from table where not 98h=type each events
```

Comment: great explanation and clever use of key each, I will read for more about it. That's what I was looking for. One more thing, in the table metadata, how do I ungroup metadata for each rows and join to their respective id rows and make it a table joined with respective rows?

Comment: Added a few thoughts in answer

Answer (score 1):

The data returned from the API contains dictionaries with two distinct sets of keys:

```
q)distinct key each res`data
`id`bundle`results`metadata`errors
`id`bundle`results`metadata
```

One simple way to convert this to a table is to `enlist` each dictionary first, converting them to tables, then joining with `uj`:

```
q)(uj/)enlist each res`data
id                      bundle        results                       metadata ..
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------..
"compound"              0n            (,`oneDayTotalFees)!,0n       `source`i..
"swapr-ethereum"        "swapr"       (,`oneDayTotalFees)!,24.78725 `category..
...
```

This works as `uj` generalises the join operator `,`, allowing different schemas with common elements to be combined.